# How to write regex in XSD

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am writing XSD pattern restriction and I have the following strings that are valid

- ^user
- ^user.name
- {$username}
- {$user1.name}

And the below are invalid

- user
- User
- USER
- {username}
- {user@name}

The rule is to start the string with either ^ or {. If we start with { then next character should be $ and the word should end with }. No uppercase or @ symbol allowed.

I have tried this `<xs:pattern value="[\^\{].*\w+\}?"/>` this work partially but doesnt satisfy all conditions

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the current `<xsd:pattern value="????"/>` value? What does not work?

Comment: I have tried this <xs:pattern value="[\^\{].*\w+\}?"/> this work partially but doesnt satisfy all conditions

Comment: Try `"^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?|\{$[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?}"`

Comment: Please try that in the XSD code, not at any online testers (unless you use an XSD regex specific site). XSD regex engine is very specific.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.. I have added in XSD.    <xs:attribute name="label"> 
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?|\{$[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>.  But I am seeing an error "InvalidRegex: Pattern value '^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?|\{$[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?}' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'Unexpected meta character.'.xsd(InvalidRegex)"

Comment: Aha, that is interesting. So, try escaping `^` and `$`, use `"\^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?|\{\$[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?}"`

Comment: Thank you...I took a que from you comment and made small change :  <xs:pattern value="[\^][a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?|\{\$[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?\}"/>. this works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
<xs:attribute name="label">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?|\{\$[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

XSD regex are always anchored, so the two alternatives in the above regex must match the whole string.

They match

- `\^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?` - `^` char, then 1+ lowercase ASCII letters, then an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `|` - or
- `\{\$` - `{$` substring
- `[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters, then an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `}` - a `}` char.